# What crystal structure have electrons in Wigner crystal?

Tags: condensed-matter

If electrons form a crystal in the Wigner crystal what is the structure of that crystal? cubic, bcc, fcc,...?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_crystal says BCC in 3d, although I would go through the citations, since it is not clear what the source of the statement is.

Answer (score -3):

Triangular in structure,to reflct off of each other,thereby amplifying the energy put into it by 3

Comment: Triangles are 2D.  A crystal is 3D.  Perhaps you meant tetrahedral?